# Android, passing LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and TextView between methods

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to create a thread that update a certain TextView.  I have already setup the LinearLayout, RelativeLayout and TextView in the onCreate() method; I merely want to update that information.  Everything compiles fine it's just when I execute it on my phone I get a force close run time error.

I have a feeling the issue resides with the onRefresh(...){ and how I pass that information.  Would anyone be able to clarify how to pass that information correctly?

Thank you!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Define String(s)
    String infoText = "Push button to test";
    String buttonLabelA = "Show Hello!";

    //Setup screen orientation
    LinearLayout mainWindow = new LinearLayout(this);
    mainWindow.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    //Set title
    setTitle("JOHello");

    //Set the static text that will appear in the window
    TextView label = new TextView(this);
    label.setText(infoText);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, 50);
    params1.leftMargin = 15;
    params1.topMargin = 5;
    mainWindow.addView(label, params1);

    //Set button
    Button greetingButton = new Button(this);//instantiate greeting button
    greetingButton.setText(buttonLabelA);//set button text
    mVB localVB = new mVB();
    greetingButton.setOnClickListener(localVB);//link button click to event
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 75);
    params2.leftMargin = 100;
    params2.topMargin = 100;
    mainWindow.addView(greetingButton, params2);//add button to current view*/


    //Changeable text
    TextView chgTxt = new TextView(this);
    chgTxt.setText(localVB.greetingText);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, 50);
    params3.leftMargin = 15;
    params3.topMargin = 600;
    mainWindow.addView(chgTxt, params3);


    setContentView(mainWindow);

    doRefresh(mainWindow, params3, chgTxt);
}




private void doRefresh(final LinearLayout localWindow, final RelativeLayout.LayoutParams localParams, final TextView localText){
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {  
            localText.setText("It truly works!");
            localWindow.addView(localText, localParams);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

I have made the variables global Eureeka! I now have a run time issue where it hangs when Handler is declared:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final Handler handler = new Handler();//Hanging!?
public LinearLayout mainWindow = new LinearLayout(this);
public TextView mainText = new TextView(this);
public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mainParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(400, 50);


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

...
}

public void doRefresh(){
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {  
            mainText.setText("It fucking works");
            mainWindow.addView(mainText, mainParams);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Here is the log cat:

> 02-13 23:32:56.204: E/AndroidRuntime(11184):  ... 11 more

```
02-13 23:33:43.500: I/dalvikvm(11215): Debugger is active
02-13 23:33:43.580: I/System.out(11215): Debugger has connected
02-13 23:33:43.580: I/System.out(11215): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 23:33:43.781: I/System.out(11215): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 23:33:43.981: I/System.out(11215): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 23:33:44.181: I/System.out(11215): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 23:33:44.381: I/System.out(11215): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 23:33:44.581: I/System.out(11215): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 23:33:44.782: I/System.out(11215): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 23:33:44.982: I/System.out(11215): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 23:33:45.182: I/System.out(11215): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 23:33:45.372: I/System.out(11215): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 23:33:45.582: I/System.out(11215): debugger has settled (1410)
02-13 23:34:14.651: D/AndroidRuntime(11215): Shutting down VM
02-13 23:34:14.661: W/dalvikvm(11215): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.johello/com.johello.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1738)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1915)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:299)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:116)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at com.johello.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1730)
02-13 23:34:14.711: E/AndroidRuntime(11215):    ... 11 more
```

Thanks again for your help guys!

Comment: declare global variables instead of local ones and thread can use them

Comment: You've added the `TextView` chgTxt to `mainWindow` once already. Why would you want add it again inside the `doRefresh()` method?

Comment: TactMayers: I would like to do it in dorefresh() in general it's just getting it to do it there is an issue.  This is like a 10th (maybe more) rewrite of the code trying to get text to change when Iclickabutton.                                                      Pulkit Sethi: defining them in a different scope worked, thanks! (not sure if they are technically global at the moment).                                                            codeMagic: I posted a logcat of the new runtime error issue. I am new to Java and even newer to Eclipse so I am trying to make heads and tails of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NullPointerException` stack trace is caused by the change you made to the view creation.  You can't instantiate views like this:

```
public LinearLayout mainWindow = new LinearLayout(this);
public TextView mainText = new TextView(this);
```

as member variables because the `Context` they need (your `this` pointer) doesn't have valid resources until `onCreate()` is called.  If you want to declare the references to the view as class members, that's fine; but instantiate them in `onCreate()`, a la:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public LinearLayout mainWindow;
    public TextView mainText;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mainWindow = new LinearLayout(this);
        mainText = new TextView(this);

        mainWindow.addView(mainText);

        setContentView(mainWindow);
    }

}
```

The crash you were probably receiving with your old code is that a view cannot be added to a parent multiple times, and doing so will throw an exception.  In the old code, the last `mainWindow.addView()` inside and later `localWindow.addView()` from inside the `Handler` attempt to add the same `TextView` to the same parent view twice.

Comment: Hey thanks a bunch for clearing that up.  I'm more of a C language guy so Java and the Android API is really giving me a run for my money.  I definitely need to spend more time with this API.  I have it working now thanks again, especially Pulkit Sethi and Devunwired!!!!!